# Não consigo alterar a senha do root no mysql, da erro na hora de usar o comando

Tags: mysql

No momento que dou o comando

`update user set authentication_string=password('root') where user = 'root';`

para trocar a senha do root o seguinte erro aparece no mysql:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('root') where user = 'root'' at line 1

A sequência de comandos que eu dei antes de chegar nesse erro foi:

```
sudo service mysql stop

sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

sudo service mysql start

sudo mysql -u root

use mysql;

show tables;

describe user;

update user set authentication_string=password('root') where user = 'root';
```

Comment: [1] Da uma olhada nesse link: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099028/error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-want-to-configure-a-pa), creio que vai achar sua resposta.

Comment: Encontrei a respostas o comando `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';`, funcionou para mim, obrigado.